# NodeJS string command filter data in Mongodb then MongoError: $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use NodeJS and Mongodb. I attemp make query by NodeJS and I found some problems too hard for fix.

Code is create command query on NodeJS

```js
function DeleteItem(db, data) {

var jobj = "{'Item_ID':1},{'Item_ID':2}";
    db.collection('P_Item').update(
        {
            $and: [{ 'Shop_ID': data.shopid }],
            $or: [jobj]
        },

        {
            $set: { 'Item_Delete': 1 }
        },

        {
            'upsert': false
        }
    );
    console.log("DeleteItem");
}
```

When function working I will get the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): MongoError: $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full
>   objects

If I write code replace on `jobj` not use `var` object that work

```js
function DeleteItem(db, data) {

    db.collection('P_Item').update(
        {
            $and: [{ 'Shop_ID': data.shopid }],
            $or: [{'Item_ID':1},{'Item_ID':2}]
        },

        {
            $set: { 'Item_Delete': 1 }
        },

        {
            'upsert': false
        }
    );
    console.log("DeleteItem");
}
```

But I don't want to use this way, because `jobj` will got number object is not equal each time.

How can I use `$or:[jobj]` work without error?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining `jobj` this way: `var jobj = "{'Item_ID':1},{'Item_ID':2}";`, type of jobj will be `string` but we need an array of objects for `$or`.

So, if jobj have to be string, you can change it's type like this:

```
db.collection('P_Item').update(
    {
        $and: [{ 'Shop_ID': data.shopid }],
        $or: JSON.parse("[" + jobj.replace(/'/g, '"') + "]")
    },

    {
        $set: { 'Item_Delete': 1 }
    },

    {
        'upsert': false
    }
);
```